# Windows failed to apply the Deployed Printer Connections settings

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I have created a new policy in my domain using Group Policy Management. I have successfully deployed it from Print Server Management. However, when I run the command "gpupdate /force" on my client machine, I receive an error message. I have attached screenshots of the error message for reference. Please find the screenshots below:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: When you ran the report it instructed you to run, what does it say?

Comment: Deployed Printer Connections failed due to the error listed below.

Additional information may have been logged. Review the Policy Events tab in the console or the application event log for events between 3/8/2024 1:17:32 AM and 3/8/2024 1:17:33 AM.

Comment: And the event log?

Comment: I really didn't know the problem. I tried a lot of methods. I couldn't find the problem.